# Ошибка при чтении локального json файла (React)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Пытаюсь прочитать локальный json файл, использую найденный фрагмент кода для решения задачи:

```
function ProductBox() {

    function readTextFile(file, callback) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    readTextFile("products.json", function(text){
        var data = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
    return(
        <div>
            {readTextFile.data}
        </div>
    );
}
export default ProductBox;
```

Появляются следующие ошибки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LOZH.png

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В файле невалидный json, потому что ошибка на строке:

```
var data = JSON.parse(text);
```

Comment: с json'ом все ок. Скорее всего ошибка в том, что text undefined почему-то

Comment: Перед callback(rawFile.responseText); поставьте console.log(rawFile.responseText); и посмотрите, что возвращается.

Comment: возвращается html

Comment: Поэтому ошибка при распарсивании json. Проблема с доступом к файлу.